# How to call a dialog box and set vertical scroll bar for a div in Cypress test

Tags: javascript, cypress

In my web application, on click of an icon system will display a pop up dialog box with many text fields and drop down select fields. While running the test using Cypress test runner, some how vertical scroll bar disappears. Due to that I am unable to see the bottom fields in dialog box. So here I am trying to set a vertical scroll bar for that `div` class via javascript function as below. But I am getting a `TypeError: Cannot set property 'overflow' of undefined` in Cypress. Is this is the right way to achieve this ?

```
cy.window().then((win) => {
    cy.addScroll()       
    cy.get('#TextQuestionDialog_Mandatory').select("Mandatory")
 })

function addScroll(){
  const ele = document.getElementById('details-dialog');
  console.log(ele);
  ele.style.overflow = "scroll";
  ele.style.height = "350px";
}
```

TypeError: Cannot set property 'overflow' of undefined

Comment: You say you can not see the fields. Can cypress see the elements if you query for them? I would be more interested to find out why the scroll bar disappears. Perhaps you can see the size of the screen in cypress or something.

Comment: I can see the fields, but since the vertical scrollbar disappears in the pop-up dialog I can't scroll down to type or select my fields. So I was thinking about an approach to add the vertical scrollbar

Comment: That sucks. I was hoping even though you could not see them, cypress could still find them in the DOM and type or select them. I will look around to see if I can find why this happens

Comment: Maccurt, I left the complex way of fitting 'scroll bar' inside dialog pop up. Instead I did a simple `cy.reload()` which actual refresh the page, so next time when  I access the Dialog popup the scroll was there...the problem is solved now

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue.
Cypress does not work when we try to scroll the child elements like MUI dialog.
It will not find elements in DOM too.

Just a slight difference in my case was that I needed to scroll Horizontally.

```
cy.viewport('macbook-15');
```

Just change the viewport permanently or temporarily based on your need.
This will eliminate the requirement of scrolling.